# Laravel Echo, Pusher js, React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, laravel-echo, pusher-js

Echo is working perfectly with pusherjs on react native. My problem is with the state change on my functional component.

```
  echo
    .join(`streaming-channel-${streamID}`)
    .here(users => setUsers(users))
    .joining(user => {
      console.log('----------------current users', users.current);
      setUsers([...users.current, user]);
      console.log('---------------users', users);
    })
    .leaving(user => {
      console.log('Leaving'), console.log('user', user);
    });
```

From the above code snippet, I'm joining the channel successfully and receiving current and joining users respectfully. Upon receiving current users (`.here(users => setUsers(users))`) my component re-renders multiple times, I have tried useEffect but the same problem occurs. On joining, I use React.useRef to get up-to-date users from state.

How do I solve the re-render issue on updating my state.